# How can the field name on the date card be removed?

Tags: powerbi, field-names

[image]

As I prepare the current date card, the field name is also displayed, but I do not want that field name to appear on the card.

I tried to delete that field name, but I couldn't discover a way to do so. How to delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to format and switch off Category label.

[image]